# React Native detect changes in Navigation Type setting on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

We have a component that needs to fill the height of the available screen; nothing more, nothing less. We do this by getting the window height via Dimensions.

I recently discovered on android that you can disable the entire navigation bar which causes some issues. When the user has the app open, then changes the setting of the navigation bar, the component stays the height from before the switch (too large when the bar was turned on, too small if the bar was turned off). `Dimensions.get('window').Height` doesn't update. Is there a way to detect this change (so I can do it via a state possibly) or to force the Dimensions component?

EDIT: I checked the setting's name. I'm looking for a way to detect changes to the Navigation Typesetting, the same way NetInfo detects changes in the network.

Comment: What have you tried so far (as code example)? The initial hunch is that you just should use `flex:1` to get that stretched correctly. But it really helps to provide correct answer when there's some code involved